# how to get image from url in iphone

Tags: iphone, imageview

I am new to iPhone.Im my application i want getting image from url

I tried the fallowing code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 UIImageView *UV=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
 [self.view addSubview:UV];    
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdON9USAAAAAO9AtfFsuLxBY1l-yNDBoJcb1Jeb"];

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
    UV.image=image;
}
```

but image is not displayed in image view .can any one help to me
thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at SDWebImage: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Your URL isn't pointing to an image file.

Comment: Your procedure is right. But unfortunately there is no image in the URL.

Comment: your code is fine try with this url `http://rubyquiz.strd6.com/quizzes/191/image6a.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you give isn't an image so it won't work.

More importantly, while it looks OK, it's absolutely not recommended to do it like this.

The call to `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is blocking the main thread during the download, making the app unresponsive.

Take a look at some open-source projects as mentioned by Antaresm.
You may also want to look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/), put it in your project and then, all you have to write is

```
[UV setImageWithURL:url];
```